# Qunit and JQuery 1.5.2

Tags: jquery, qunit

Following code works with JQuery 1.4.4. The result it prints is:

Tests completed in 152 milliseconds.
1 tests of 1 passed, 0 failed.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/git/qunit.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        test("verify results", function () {
            ok(true, "all pass");
        });
    });
</script>
```

If changed to use JQuery 1.5.2,

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The result it prints is:

Tests completed in 2426 milliseconds.
33 tests of 34 passed, 1 failed.

Is it a bug in JQuery 1.5.2?

The full source is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">
                <h2>Test Results</h2>
                <div id="qunit-testrunner-toolbar"></div>
                <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
                <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
            </div>

            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/git/qunit.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                test("verify result after post", function () {
                    ok(true, "all pass");
                });
            });
            </script>

            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're testing the same set of tests (1 test vs 34?). What does the failing test look like?

Comment: All I have is one time one test:  ok(true, "all pass");  With JQuery 1.5.2, it reports 34 tests, 1 failed w/o telling what failed.

Comment: What browser are you running this on? I just tried it out on Firefox 4 and it runs fine with both 1.4.4 and 1.5.2

Comment: I use IE 9 and Chrome. In Chrome it says 690 tests of 691 passed, 1 failed even with jQuery 1.4.x. It is strange.

Comment: I updated the question with the full source. Notice the test script is inside several divs. It works if moved the script to body. Why this is different?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- The `qunit.js` script assumes the `id="qunit"` atrribute/value pair exists
- The `qunit.css` reference is missing

For future reference, use the official boilerplate as a starting point:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  <script src="qunit.js"></script>
  <script src="tests.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```